# What should an ideal Interaction Design Portfolio Include

Tags: interaction-design, ux-field, jobs, portfolio

I am preparing my Interaction Design portfolio. I would like to as what should my portfolio include. What all deliverables should be included in the portfolio?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about career advice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We're looking at a lot of portfolios these days.  The high fidelity glossy finished UI is always nice to look at, but what we're looking for is a portfolio that can demonstrate a working knowledge of gathering UI design requirements (heuristic evals, use case reviews, stakeholder interviews, usability test data) and demonstrate a process by which "problem solving" for the best possible design approach was made during the course of the design cycle.

In short, if you're portfolio can demonstrate your process and working knowledge of a sound and repeatable user centered design approach - then you're more than half way there...

Your wires should be annotated with callouts and demonstrate interactivity (hover, click, status, notifications, etc.).

Once you have those bases covered... then you can add those shiny polished UI shots.  G'luck!

Comment: Thanks Jon...certainly helpful...will post the link soon.. :)

Answer (score 4):

Besides the usual images showing various stages, I would love to see one or two projects from start to finish.  From conceptual sketches to polished product.

**UX isn't a destination, it's a journey**.  Show that journey and you will stand out.

It would also be good to see some analysis of websites showing where you think they went wrong and why.  Better if they are well known sites, or even your potential employer's site.